# How to add a mouseEntered event for each element of a JList

Tags: java, mouseevent, jlist

I have a program and I want to add a mouseEntered event for each element in the JList. When the cursor is on an element (not clicking) of the JList, this has to change its format so you know which element will you select. I read about a ListCellRendered but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: It is very hard to help without looking at what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you just try it with mouse event of Mouse Entered.
but without clicking on the list view it's not possible to find the position.
because the JList is on the ScrollView so it the position of the mouse could not identify the where it standing on the List.